# Avoid displaying in split second when css is not applied yet

Tags: javascript, css

In my client Javascript application, there is a fraction of second when the css is not yet loaded and the the page displayed bare html. How can I avoid this (for example using blank page and detect when css is ready)?

Comment: include your stylesheets before your scripts

Comment: As @Maxx said, include your stylesheets before your scripts. Include them in the `<head>` tag if possible.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see why this is off topic. HINT: Post code and effort

Answer (score 6):

Add this style to your `body` tag

```
<body style="display:none">
```

And add this to your CSS file:

```
body { display: block !important; }
```

@somethinghere suggested that visually impaired people might not load stylesheets, so this solution would prevent them to access the web page. This would be fixed by adding this small script in the body tag:

```
<body style="display:none" onload="document.body.removeAttribute('style');">
```

Comment: What about users who don't load stylesheets (say, the visually impaired)? The suggestions made in the comments above are better, simply include your style before it evaluates your content.

Comment: If they block CSS would the inline style not be blocked too?

Comment: as i know `onload` fires when images loaded (besides other entities). So, i don't think its good idea to use this answer.

Comment: Thanks for the update for the visually impaired, however, they usually have javascript turned of as well :) It might be best to add a script right below your body opening tag that adds the `display: none` to it (since the element exists at that time). Then remove it with CSS. Everybody happy!

Comment: if it's not related with no css, the css will load before the images, and it will make the body visible.

Comment: @TahaPaksu You speak in riddles. If you use `body onload=""` it _will_ fire only _after_ images were loaded (you are looking for the `DOMContentReady` event in that case). If you are telling me that what I said is irrelevant because its no CSS, you are breaking the site for a specific set of users that already have trouble with this for **no** reason. Thank god you have great eyes, mate. Many people _do not_.